# Who is the child voice actor of the Catalyst in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I have looked for the name of the voice actor who does the voice of the young boy/catalyst, but nowhere online seems to have this information. I know that the voice of the catalyst includes Shepard's voices as well, but I'm referring specifically to the "main" voice, which is shared with the young boy as well.

I'm also looking for the voice actor for the young boy in the post-credits cut scene, who talks with the Stargazer. I'm not sure if it is the same voice actor or a different one.

Comment: The closing credits for the game can be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WETb5M2l_o0) where the "cast" is listed around 2:20.  However, there doesn't appear to be an entry for the Catalyst.  At the end of this list is an "Additional Voices" section that they may be lumped into.

Comment: Googling has led me to various claims that the Catalyst shares a voice actor with [the boy that Shepard encounters in the first mission of ME3](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1839558/trivia?item=tr2217029) (Prologue: Earth), [Vigil from ME1](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/995452-mass-effect-3/63264907) (voiced by David Shaughnessy), or [a young Elliot Alderson from episode 10 of some (2015?) season of the show *Mr. Robot*](https://redd.it/3kh1u7) (Elliot is portrayed as a child by Aidan Liebman in seasons 1–2, Alex Bento in season 3, and Evan Whitten in season 4). Not sure what's true.